# Is there a way to download the stock values of companies?

Tags: stock-exchanges, investment-strategies, stock-valuation

Recently, my bank approached me with an offer for an investment fund, its basket containing about thirty stocks.

I wanted to know about the evolution of those stocks, so I tried looking for "koers pfizer" on Google (just as an example, "koers" is the Dutch word for stock value and graph) in order to get information on the last stock values.

This worked, but what I got was some interactive tool, where I could get the single stock value for one single moment (like five years ago).

Having done that for two periods (five years and the entire stock exchange lifetime), I have serious doubts:

- The stock values went up in average ±3.95% a year in the entire lifetime (great fund!).
- The stock values went up in average ±0.8% a year in the last five years (what a bummer!).

In order to do a better analysis, I'd like to investigate the stock values before Corona hit, but in order to do that, I would need to get the stock values of three years ago.

This would mean: do the whole Google search again, for every single company, and choose the right spot interactively on the graph in order to get the value.
No, thanks, I would like to do this in a more appropriate manner, simply by downloading the stock values, maybe in a CSV format, or so.

But where can I do that from? Is there some website for which I could launch a command like:

```
wget www.website.com/company_stockvalues/?depth=forever
```

... or something similar? (Having a different website per stock-exchange is not a problem at all, I'm happy with everything I can get)

Comment: Have you tried searching "stock price history"? That said, if you're researching stock you should be less worried about what it's done in the past and more worried about what it's going to do _in the future_. That's a much harder question to answer but more relevant that just going off of momentum.

Comment: Or "stock price api free" and do a bit of programming. But, yes, "past results are no guarantee of future performance." Especially shorter-term performance. And you're neglecting dividends. And unless you're willing to do much deeper research than this, betting on any one stock is risky; _DIVERSIFY_ (most easily done with index funds) to get something closer to overall market performance (which has been more like 8% than 4%, in the long run, though again that's for reference rather than a guarantee.

Comment: The Yahoo Finance website provides strock prices for US stocks that you can download in .csv (spreadsheet) format.  It also has lots of other economic data.

Comment: You can have a look at the Xerox chart [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/155067/109107) to see how useful past performance is.

Comment: Please join me in voting to reopen this question.  This is not a question seeking a product or service recommendation.  Instead, this is a question asking how to do something that is related to personal finance (investing).  See [this meta answer](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2896/10997) for more information on the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [GOOGLEFINANCE function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en) in Google Docs to get the stock values on any days that you want.

Comment: Thanks. I've made a spreadsheet, based on the mentioned `GoogleFinance()` function and that gave me very clear information on what to do. As far as the reopening of this question is concerned: I've asked to reopen it but my reputation seems to be too low to follow that process.